# Python usage not printing

Tags: python

im creating my first python "app" and im having problems with the args or lack of. If i execute the script with no arguments id expect a message stating usage, but instead im getting the following error

**ERROR**

```
unknown@ubuntu:~$ ./attack.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./attack.py", line 60, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "./attack.py", line 57, in main
print fread(FWORD)
File "./attack.py", line 19, in fread
flist = open(FWORD).readlines()
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import sys, getopt, socket, fileinput, traceback
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


def usage():
    print "-h --help: help\n"
    print "-f --file: File to read potential Sub-domains from.\n"
    print "-p --PROXY: PROXY address and port. e.g http://192.168.1.64:8080\n"
    print "-d --DOMAIN: DOMAIN to bruteforce.\n"
    print "-t --thread: Thread count.\n"
    print "-e: Turn debug on.\n"
    sys.exit()

def fread(FWORD, *args):
    flist = open(FWORD).readlines()
    return flist

#def addcheck(fcontent):



def main(argv):
    PROXY = None
    DOMAIN = None
    FWORD= None
    try:
            opts, argv =getopt.getopt(argv, "h:f:p:d:t:e",["help", "file=", "PROXY=", "DOMAIN=", "thread="])

    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
            print str(err)
            usage()
            sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
            if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
                    usage()
                    sys.exit()
            elif opt in ("-f", "--file"):
                    FWORD = arg
            elif opt in ("-p", "--PROXY"):
                    PROXY = arg
            elif opt in ("-d", "--DOMAIN"):
                    DOMAIN = arg
            elif opt in ("-t", "--thread"):
                    thread = arg
            elif opt in '-e':
                    global _debug
                    _debug = 1
            else:
                    usage()
                    sys.exit()

    print fread(FWORD)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Ok thanks all for the comments and pointers. ZMO im going to go with docopt it looks clean and simple (simple just like me). Im not entire sure what i need to do to my old code so am uploading what i think i need to do. Can anyone tell me if this is the right direction?
What do i do with `def main()` now? and

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, getopt, socket, fileinput, traceback
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def fread(FWORD, *args):
    flist = open(FWORD).readlines()
    return flist

def main(argv):

"""
Usage:
  your_script.py [-f <file>] [-p <proxy>] [-d <domain>] [-t] [-v]
  your_script.py -h | --help

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  -f --file     File to read potential Sub-domains from.
  -p --proxy    Proxy address and port. [default: http://127.0.0.1:8080]
  -d --domain   Domain to bruteforce.
  -t --thread   Thread count.
  -v --verbose  Turn debug on.
"""

# […] your code (NOT SURE WHAT CODE YOU MEAN? 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')
    print fread(FWORD)
```

Comment: You should not send argv as an argument to main. This is not C/C++.

Comment: You should consider using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) instead of `optparse`; `optparse` is really sparse in what it can do with required arguments, for example.

Comment: Use `./attack.py -f /path/to/file.py`.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik Why not?

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you give me an example of how to to use argparse instead of what i currently have?

Comment: I'd use [docopt](http://docopt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead, if you aren't married to the stdlib.

Comment: If you dont pass -f followed by a file, FWORD will be none and open(none) throws an exception. Follow @BleedingFingers's instruction.

Comment: Using ALL_CAPS names for non-constants is also poor style; anyone needing to maintain your code later will hate you.

Comment: @LearningCode: looks like zmo is planning to include one in his post.

Comment: @Wooble they are constants, but im guessing my idea of constants arent the same? Although they are variables they will be the same value in the script.

Comment: If you assign to something conditionally, it's not a constant.

Comment: @Wooble ill rename and keep it in mind. So constants are only things that are "constant" in the script. IE a value that isnt parsed to the script but is native and doesnt change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `geptopt` is deprecated in modern python, you should use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) instead. I personally prefer the 3rd party [docopt](http://docopt.org)
2. It's useless to give the `sys.argv` array as argument to `main()` because you import the `sys` module globally in your module context (and there are many other things you'd use from sys aside from `argv`). Your code would only make sense if you were doing the import in the `if __name__ == "__main__"`, but then that would be not good python practice. A better thing to do is to actually parse the arguments and then give the returned [`NamedTuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) as an argument to `main()`.

### Argparse example

```
# […] your code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Your script.')
    parser.add_argument('--file', '-f', metavar='FILE', dest='file', type=file,
                       help='File to read potential Sub-domains from.')
    parser.add_argument('--proxy', '-p', dest='proxy', action='store',
                       help='Proxy address and port.', default='http://127.0.0.1:8080')
    parser.add_argument('--domain', '-d', dest='domain', action='store',
                       help='Domain to bruteforce.')
    parser.add_argument('--thread', '-t', dest='thread', action='store_true',
                       help='Thread count.')
    parser.add_argument('--verbose', '-v', dest='verbose', action='store_true',
                       help='Turn debug on.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

### docopt example

```
Your script presentation.

"""
Usage:
  your_script.py [-f <file>] [-p <proxy>] [-d <domain>] [-t] [-v]
  your_script.py -h | --help

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  -f --file     File to read potential Sub-domains from.
  -p --proxy    Proxy address and port. [default: http://127.0.0.1:8080]
  -d --domain   Domain to bruteforce.
  -t --thread   Thread count.
  -v --verbose  Turn debug on.
"""

# […] your code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='Naval Fate 2.0')
    main(arguments) # here using the parameter makes sense ;-)
```

Comment: thanks, could you explain why your importing argparse and defining it under `if __name__ = "__main__":` rather than in the `def main()` ?

Comment: because the `if __name__ == "__main__"` part is only executed when you run the script as standalone, and not if you include it as a library. So basically, it's avoiding an useless import in case you're importing your script as a library, as you may not want to parse the arguments through that module, but you may want to give leftover parameters to your `main()` function by the script importing your module.

Comment: talking about that the worst anti-pattern I know that shows why I just said is important is how [this project](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/__init__.py#L292) has argument parsing becoming a technical debt that gets in the way for any project that wants to include it as a library. Basically, if you want to control command line parsing, you then have to get the parameters from `sys.argv` and clean it up *before* you import that library.

Comment: :$ im confused lol so should i do all my imports as you did rather than at the top of my script? (sozs im a noooob)

Comment: There's no rule about that, and good practice comes with experience reading other's codes and experimenting. But my advice to you would be to always import globally, except if you *know* and *understand* what you're doing.

Comment: should I remove my `def main()` entirely if i go down the docopt route?

Comment: well, yes you should, though you may want to replace it with something more relevant to the code you want to do, like: `l33t_bruteforce(arguments)` which would be the entry point of your program/algorithm, however you use it from CLI or as a library. (designing it as a library enables you to switch to a GUI later on)

Comment: id like to design it as a libary but im not skilled enough yet im still trying to get my head around coding it as CLI. Im rather confused atm lol. Dont spose your on chat somewhere?So i could speak with you briefly?